# The Case of the Mysterious Disappearing Test Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, testing

## The Problem

I work on a Rails 3.2.2 application that's in the process of being upgraded out of the stone age. We're running a MySQL database and, up until this past week, everything's worked exactly as expected. That is, until the mystery began...

A few days ago, I went to go run my local test suite (`Test::Unit`) and saw an error that suggested my local, personal test database no longer existed. So I logged into MySQL and saw that, in fact, it didn't. Gone! Poof!

No error messages, no warnings. Nothing. Just gone.

I recreated the database and didn't give much thought to it. I figured that - somehow - I'd deleted it by accident.

Two days later, the exact same thing happened to my coworker. Test database vanished without warning.

And today, it happened to another developer on my team.

I can't find anything about this anywhere. No SO posts, no blog articles, nada.

Has anybody else experienced this? Does anyone have any idea of what could be causing it, or of what steps we could take to investigate?

Many thanks.

## The Stack

- Rails 3.2.22.2 (using the `mysql2` adapter gem)
- mysql 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Is your database.yml(or equivalent) stored in version control or is it in your .gitignore file?

Comment: You have not really given us much to go on here

Comment: it's pretty common to wipe the test database between runs. gems do this such as database_cleaner

Comment: Databases don't disappear by themselves. If they did nobody would use them. Duh. Something or somebody dropped this database. You haven't explained whether it's a MySQL server that dropped offline, or a shared copy (between you and your colleagues) of a test database, or a personal test database. You'll get more help here if you [edit] your question to give more details.

Comment: That's a great question: it was a local, personal test database. I'll add that detail in above.

Comment: @ruby_newbie it's in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've given you everything that I can think of. If you'd like more information, please request it specifically and I'll try to provide it.

Comment: @maxpleaner This I know. The strange thing, though, is the database didn't appear to be _recreated_ before the next run. Instead, I was thrown an error that said that the database doesn't exist when I ran `rake test`.